# Automatically split the Iterm2 hotkey windows terminal

Tags: macos, terminal, iterm2

I am looking to find a way to automatically split the iterm terminal into two vertical splits. So that I have two terminal to work with. I want to do this with my Hotkey windows terminal. I know I can split them using `cmd + d` option. I could not find any ways to in preference setting. So again I want windows to split automatically every-time I start a new iterm terminal without me pressing `cmd +d`! Let me know if there is any way.

thanks so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is well described in: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/22445/how-can-i-save-tabs-in-iterm-2-so-they-restore-the-next-time-the-app-is-run

---

You can Save and Restore Window Arrangement with <kbd>⇧ ⌘ S</kbd> and <kbd>⇧ ⌘ R</kbd> options under the Window screen in iTerm2

You can start the default Arrangement Option to enable are at **Preferences** -> **General** -> **Startup**  -> **Open default window arrangement** .

You can add arrangements with the <kbd>⇧ ⌘ S</kbd> and manage them under **Preferences** -> **Arrangements** tab .

[image]

Comment: Ahh! Sorry my bad! Tried to search extensively before I asked here, but clearly did not searched enough! thanks Cheers